# Hunting for some properties of a series similar to Riemann zeta function.

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

I happened to meat a alternated zeta function in D. Borwein's [paper](http://novaprd-lb.newcastle.edu.au/vital/access/manager/Repository/uon:14223;jsessionid=341837E13A7848C9CD65C9A93FED4866?exact=sm_subject%3A%22Madelung%E2%80%99s%20constant%22)(see eq. 40 of his paper). The series is
$$
L_{-3}(s)=1-\frac{1}{2^s}+\frac{1}{4^s}-\frac{1}{5^s}+\frac{1}{7^s}-\frac{1}{8^s}+\dots
$$
where the multiple of 3, i.e. 3,6,9,$\dots$ are neglected in the summation with the alternated sgn "+1" and "-1" unchanged. Since I am not really familiar with this kind of series or function, so I just wonder that is this kind of series has a name, or can you provide me with more information about the series?

Comment: It is just the Dirichlet L-function associated with the Legendre symbol $\pmod{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

A series of the form 
$$ 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{n^s} 
$$
for some sequence $(a_n)_n$of complex numbers is called a [Dirichlet series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series). 
When the sequence $(a_n)_n$ is of the form $a_n = \chi(n)$ for a [Dirichlet character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character) $\chi$, then it is called a [Dirichlet $L$-Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function).

This specific one is as mentioned in a commented one defined by a Dirichlet character modulo $3$, the non-prinicipal one.